# Assembly - assign int value to string

Tags: variables, assembly, nasm, assign

It is possible to assign an int value to a string in assembly?

For example, I put >> rat = 2, and when I call a program that uses the variables, if I put >> rat + 2, it has to return 4.

And, if it's possible, which is the best way to do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to store an integer in a *variable*, that just happens to be named using a string? That's very different from how rkhb interpreted your question, but I think it is more in line with your actual question, judging from the tags you've used.

There are two basic types of variables supported in NASM: *initialized* data and *uninitialized* data.

With initialized data, you assign a static value when you declare the variable. Actually, initialized data is more like a *constant*, but you name it symbolically. `DB` (Declare Byte), `DW` (Declare Word), `DD` (Declare Doubleword), and `DQ` (Declare Quadword) are the commands used to declare initialized data. So you could do:

```
rat  DD  2
```

And then somewhere in your code, do:

```
mov  eax, DWORD [rat]
add  eax, 2
; eax now contains 4
```

With uninitialized data, you are basically just reserving space to hold data. This data is not initialized statically; you fill it at run-time. You use `RESB` (Reserve Byte), `RESW` (Reserve Word), `RESD` (Reserve Doubleword), and `RESQ` (Reserve Quadword) for this; for example:

```
rat  RESD 1     ; reserve space for 1 DWORD-sized value
```

And then later in your code, you would go:

```
call GetValue           ; returns value in EAX
mov  DWORD [rat], eax   ; store value in 'rat'
```

This is all explained in [Chapter 3](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.12.02/html/nasmdoc3.html) of the NASM manual.

Answer (score 0):

That's wasn't what I was looking for, but thanks

I'm trying to make a calculator with variables with NASM

So, as a Casio calculator (for example), that you can put variables like X, Y, M, Z and others, and then you can assign values to those variables

That is what I'm looking for, not inside the code, but in screen.

Again, thanks for help, it helped me with another error with my code